# Possible to extend a Vietnamese tourist visa in Dong Hoi?

Tags: visas, vietnam, visa-extensions, tourist-visas

I have an Australian passport with a C1 tourist visa for Vietnam. Is it possible for me to get a standard 30 day (or longer) extension for my visa in Dong Hoi (the major town east of Phong Nha National Park)?

I would prefer answers from people who have actually done this, and as much information as possible including: where it was done, how much it cost, how long the visa extension was for, and how long it took.

Comment: See also: [Renewing or getting a new visa in Vietnam?](http://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/19559)

Answer (score 4):

No, you will need to send your passport to Hanoi, Ho Chi Minh City or Danang to have your visa extended. You can also find a travel agency in Dong Hoi who can assist you in extending your visa.

Comment: Do you have any recommendations or information regarding specific travel agencies in Dong Hoi?

Answer (score 2):

I was told by a fellow Australian living near Phong Nha (about 40km from Dong Hoi) that there *is* an immigration office in Dong Hoi, but they *do not* do visa extensions. I did not have the patience to look for alternatives in Dong Hoi.

When we were passing through Hue (to the south) we found plenty of places who would arrange the extension for us, so that is likely the nearest place to reliably get it done. However, please note that all of the places we inquired at told us that the visa would *not* be extended, but replaced. Apparently they cancel your original visa and give you a new one valid for **30 days from the date you apply for the extension, not from the date of expiry on your first visa**.